# how to slice 2D numpy array based on 2 1D arrays containing initial and final indexes

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, slice

I have a 2D numpy array, let's say it has shape 4x10 (4 rows and 10 columns). I have 2 1D arrays that have the initial and final indexes, so they are both 20x1. For an example, let's say

```
initial = [1, 2, 4, 5]
final = [3, 6, 8, 6]
```

then I'd like to get

```
data[0,1:3]
data[1,2:6]
data[2,4:8]
data[3,5:6]
```

Of course, each of those arrays would have different size, so I'd like to store them in a list.
If I were to do it with a `for` loop, it'd look like this:

```
arrays = []
for i in range(4):
    slice = data[i,initial[i]:final[i]]
    arrays.append(slice)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I'd rather avoid use a `for` loop, because my actual data is huge.

Comment: `4x10 (10 rows and 10 columns)` ? Maybe there's some issue in the numbers you mention..

Comment: How else are you going to get a list?  You could write the loop as a comprehension.  If the slices had the same length there's a chance of constructing a 2d array.  But not with differinvg lengths.

Comment: it doesn't have to be a list, but I don't know how to store arrays of different lengths, other than using a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) with flattened `data` (using [`numpy.ndarray.flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)) and modifying the slices:

```
sections = np.column_stack([initial, final]).flatten()

sections[::2] += np.arange(len(initial)) * data.shape[1]
sections[1::2] += sections[::2] - np.array(initial)

np.split(data.flatten(), sections)[1::2]
```